# Haskell: type variable is ambiguous for class instance

Tags: class, haskell, types

```
import qualified Prelude

class List list where
  toList :: list a -> [a]
  fromList :: [a] -> list a

data Deque a = Deque [a] [a]

instance List Deque where
  toList (Deque xs sy) = xs ++ reverse sy

  fromList xs = Deque ys (reverse zs)
    where (ys, zs) = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs
```

I am getting an error as copied below. It seems that GHCI does not detect `ys` as a Deque, and instead as a general instance of class List.

```
ghci> xs = [2, 3, 4]
ghci> ys = fromList xs
ghci> (Deque a b) = ys
ghci> toList (Deque a b)
[2,3,4]
ghci> toList ys

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    * Could not deduce (List list0) arising from a use of `toList'
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => [a]
        at <interactive>:5:1-9
      The type variable `list0' is ambiguous
      These potential instance exist:
        instance [safe] List Deque -- Defined at main.hs:12:10
    * In the expression: toList ys
      In an equation for `it': it = toList ys
```

Comment: `fromList xs = Deque xs []`. Presumably, your deque functions already handle rebalancing the two underlying lists: there's no need to duplicate that in your `List` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ghci> let xs = [2, 3, 4]
ghci> let ys = fromList ys
```

At this point the values have the most general type possible:

```
ghci> :t xs
xs :: Num a => [a]
ghci> :t ys
ys :: (List list, Num a) => list a
```

No hint of a `Deque`, which makes sense because you haven't mentioned any deques yet.

*But those variables stay the same, and they won't change their type!*

So after

```
ghci> (Deque a b) = ys
ghci> toList (Deque a b)
[2,3,4]
```

you still have the same situation for `ys`, i.e.

```
ghci> :t ys
ys :: (List list, Num a) => list a
```

Sure, you have used `ys` as a deque once, which is one way it can be used. But being polymorphic, it can just as well be any other `List` type, and GHCi won't make any guesses which it is supposed to be. But you can of course just *tell it*:

```
ghci> toList (ys :: Deque Int)
[2,3,4]
```

Or shorter

```
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications 
ghci> toList @Deque ys
[2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working as designed.  When you write:

```
λ> ys = fromList xs
```

the type assigned to `ys` is:

```
λ> :t ys
ys :: (List list, Prelude.Num a) => list a
```

That is, `ys` is a polymorphic value that can "be" any sort of `List`.

So, when you bind it to a particular pattern:

```
λ> Deque a b = ys
```

then `ys` is instantiated as a `Deque` and appropriate values are bound to `a` and `b`, but this doesn't make `ys` monomorphic.  That is, `ys` hasn't suddenly "become" a `Deque`.  Instead, it remains a polymorphic value that can be rebound to some other `List`.  For example, if you also had an instance for plain old lists:

```
instance List [] where
  toList = id
  fromList = id
```

you could instantiate `ys` at multiple types:

```
λ> xs = [2, 3, 4]
λ> ys = fromList xs
λ> Deque a b = ys     -- instantiate as Deque
λ> c:d = ys           -- instantiate as []
```

If this strikes you as odd, consider that:

```
λ> id "hello"
λ> id 'x'
```

both work, even though the first time the polymorphic value `id :: a -> a` is used, it's instantiated as `String -> String`, while the second time it's used, it's instantiated as `Char -> Char`.  It's the same principle.